# How to start nodejs server from QT program?

Tags: node.js, qt

Im working on QT program using nodejs (communicate by socket).
How can I start nodejs server automatic with the QT application?

I have installed 'forever' module to start node server easy.

qt code:

```
QProcess p;
p.start("cmd.exe", QStringList()<<"/C"<< qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/debugReq/startNode.bat");
p.waitForFinished();
qDebug() << p.readAllStandardOutput();
```

I know this works because shows script's outputs.

startNode.bat:

```
forever start server.js
```

Server works when i run it by clicking  startNode.bat file but when i run from QT it only show outputs but server doesnt start.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: read about ``QProcess``

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2623460/2531178