# How to start a process in Windows using QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I'm trying to start a console application on Windows using QProcess's method 'start'. Official documentation says I can do it like this:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe");
```

I expect that a standard greeting message will appear in the calling application's console, but this does not happen, though the called process is running. What is wrong here?

Comment: By the way, it works as I expected it to work, when I do it using WinAPI functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622864/start-a-process-using-qprocess duplicate ?

Answer (score 1):

use of bellow example :

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString program = "explorer.exe";
QString folder = "C:\";
process->start(program, QStringList() << folder);
```

also you can use of `system()` as bellow :

```
system("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe");
```

Comment: "C:\" is not a valid string literal in C++.

Comment: What is 'this' here? I don't have any classes. I know about `system()`, but I want to use Qt's functions.

Comment: do you test `process->start()` in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

How about this static call?

```
QProcess::startDetached(FilePath,Arguments,StartInDir);
```

No need to create any objects!

Comment: Detatched works fine, but this is not what is needed.