# QProcess fails to start a process : no process found

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ros, qprocess

I am using `QProcess` in order to launch an application on my `Ubuntu 18.04` OS.
And after going through the documentation, I found that `QProcess` is the best approach.
**The problem** I have is that I am trying to launch an application via `QPushButton` on a minimal GUI but it does not work and **the error** I get from the compiler is:

> Launching LIDAR APP [EXEC] FINISHED:  0 QProcess::NormalExit [EXEC]
>   buffered DATA: "roslaunch: no process
>   found\n/home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/src/lidarboatsproject/start_lidar_deck_rosbag.sh:
>   5:
>   /home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/src/lidarboatsproject/start_lidar_deck_rosbag.sh:
>   roslaunch: not found\n"

This is the launch file I am trying to launch `start_lidar_deck_rosbag.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

killall roslaunch && sleep 10
cd /home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/
roslaunch lidar_deck lidar_deck_rosbag.launch &
```

Below the minimal GUI:

[image: lau]

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void startLidar();

private slots:
    void on_launchLidarROSBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QProcess *executeROSLidarApp;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    startLidar();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::startLidar()
{
    // Execution of the QProcess to make sure Lidar App Launcher opens:
    this->executeROSLidarApp = new QProcess(this);
    this->executeROSLidarApp->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
            [script = this->executeROSLidarApp](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
            qDebug() << "[EXEC] FINISHED: " << exitCode << exitStatus;
            if(script->bytesAvailable() > 0) qDebug() << "[EXEC] buffered DATA:" << script->readAll();
    });
    connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [script = this->executeROSLidarApp](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
            qDebug() << "[EXEC] error on execution: " << error << script->errorString();
    });
}


void MainWindow::on_launchLidarROSBtn_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Launching LIDAR APP";
    this->executeROSLidarApp->start(QStringLiteral("/bin/sh"), QStringList() << QStringLiteral("/home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/src/lidarboatsproject/start_lidar_deck_rosbag.sh"));
}
```

In order to solve the problem I researched a lot a possible solution.
I consulted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762309/qprocess-fails-to-execute-a-terminal-line-command-via-qpushbutton) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622864/start-a-process-using-qprocess). They were useful to set up the main chuck of the idea, but for some reasons I can't catch the process does not seems to start and I don't understand why the compiler is giving the error I mentioned above if I am sure that that file 100% exists.

[image: proc]

Please shed light and point to the right direction to solve this issue.

Comment: The process (`bin/sh`) is launching and executing the script. It seems as if the script itself is causing the problem. So, your c++ code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executing correctly, it is launching `/bin/sh` and executing the script and is finishing gracefully without errors. It is your script that's failing.

Here are somethings you can try:

- Make sure the process `roslaunch` exists, thats the obvious error
- Your script starts with `#!bin/bash`, but you are executing `/bin/sh` in `QProcess`. Change that to `#!/bin/sh`

PS:

You don't need to do

```cpp
 QStringList() << QStringLiteral("/home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/src/lidarboatsproject/start_lidar_deck_rosbag.sh")
```

instead, you can just use the initializer_list syntax

```
 QStringList({"/home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/src/lidarboatsproject/start_lidar_deck_rosbag.sh"});
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by and reading the question. I tried both your solutions but unfortunately it still not work

Comment: regardless, the problem here isn't with `QProcess`, it is with the script. Maybe you should try running the script directly in the terminal to see if it executes correctly or not?